# Running a single class Test causes all tests to be run when delegating build actions to maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a java project in IntelliJ in which I've selected "delegate build/run to maven". whenever I right click next to a class name or test class method nam enad say "run ____Test", it runs my whole suite with 1000s of test classes. That's not what I want. I want to run just a single test from IntelliJ.

IntelliJ version: 2022.1.4
Maven version: 3.8.1

Comment: Select the class in IntelliJ and run it there?

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with run configuration created when you execute test? Also please check the issue with the latest ID version.